# How do you declare a function that is executed automatically by library in a TypeScript declaration file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, typescript-typings, p5.js

In [p5.js](https://p5js.org/) there are functions like `draw()`, `setup()` and `mousePressed()` that is "declared" by user then never used because they are executed automatically at certain points by p5.js like so:

```
function mousePressed() {
  // do something when the mouse is pressed.
}
```

For some reason WebStorm recognized that `draw()` and `setup()` shouldn't give "unused function" errors, but it didn't recognize `mousePressed()`.

How do I configure my `p5.d.ts` file to declare such a function?

**edit 1:**
What I want is for WebStorm stop giving "Unused function" errors when it is used by a library (p5.js in my case). Presumably by adding something to my p5 TypeScript definitions file.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you require. So all you want is for that function to execute automatically ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: No p5.js already does that, what I want is for WebStorm to give no "Unused function" error. Presumably by adding some code in my TypeScript file, for instance with a "Function not found" error that would be `declare function name(property: propertyType): returnType;`